# how to install ubuntu 12.04 on a new laptop

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have a new laptop with no OS on it and I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it. Can any one tell me or guide me how to install ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin#.Uk0IlyRmiSo

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please refer to this link http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/71205

Answer (score 0):

See this [The Live CD Help Article Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or this other article that explains how to boot from USB [if you already have Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on a machine you can access.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full installation instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

And more detailed technical instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html